# grunt-contrib-uglify@0.2.7 requires a peer of grunt@~0.4.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself

Tags: javascript, npm-install, grunt-contrib-uglify

I am getting the below error. Does anyone know how to fix it

> npm WARN grunt-contrib-uglify@0.2.7 requires a peer of grunt@~0.4.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

When I did `npm install` I got the below error

> added 1608 packages from 1128 contributors and audited 1615 packages in 75.474s
>
> 61 packages are looking for funding
> run `npm fund` for details
>
> found 3 vulnerabilities (1 low, 1 moderate, 1 high)
> run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

So I run `npm audit fix`:

> 62 packages are looking for funding
>
> run `npm fund` for details

```
fixed 0 of 3 vulnerabilities in 1674 scanned packages<br>
  3 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated<br>
```

In the npm WARN. I get the below errors:

> npm WARN grunt-contrib-uglify@0.2.7 requires a peer of grunt@~0.4.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

Can anyone help me fix this?

Package json

````
{
  "name": "vuekhal",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "auth0-js": "^9.12.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "core-js": "^2.6.11",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^4.0.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.3",
    "v-lazy-image": "^1.3.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.5",
    "vue-youtube": "^1.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.12.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.12.1",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.1.2",
    "axios-retry": "^3.1.2",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "grunt": "^1.3.0",
    "qs": "^6.9.1",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.0",
    "videojs": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-carousel": "^0.18.0",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.6",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-truncate-collapsed": "^2.1.0",
    "vue-video-player": "^5.0.2",
    "vue-waypoint": "^3.2.2",
    "vue2-timeago": "^1.2.6",
    "webpack": "^4.41.5",
    "webpack-bundle-tracker": "^0.4.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-log": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
  ],
  "description": "## Project setup ``` npm install ```",
  "main": "babel.config.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
````

Error Message

```
(Venv) samir@VB:~/Ahmed/Ahmed Dec 2020/Project/vuekhal$ ./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config="build/webpack.prod.conf.js"
/home/samir/Ahmed/Ahmed Dec 2020/Khal/vuekhal/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:93
                                throw err;
                                ^

Error: Cannot find module 'vue-loader/lib/plugin'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:668:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:591:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:19)
    at require (/home/samir/Ahmed/Ahmed Dec 2020/Khal/vuekhal/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/samir/Ahmed/Ahmed Dec 2020/Khal/vuekhal/build/webpack.base.conf.js:6:25)
    at Module._compile (/home/samir/Ahmed/Ahmed Dec 2020/Khal/vuekhal/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:827:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:19)
    at require (/home/samir/Ahmed/Ahmed Dec 2020/Khal/vuekhal/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/samir/Ahmed/Ahmed Dec 2020/Khal/vuekhal/build/webpack.prod.conf.js:7:27)
    at Module._compile (/home/samir/Ahmed/Ahmed Dec 2020/Khal/vuekhal/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:827:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:19)
    at require (/home/samir/Ahmed/Ahmed Dec 2020/Khal/vuekhal/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at WEBPACK_OPTIONS (/home/samir/Ahmed/Ahmed Dec 2020/Khal/vuekhal/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:114:13)
    at requireConfig (/home/samir/Ahmed/Ahmed Dec 2020/Khal/vuekhal/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:116:6)
    at /home/samir/Ahmed/Ahmed Dec 2020/Khal/vuekhal/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:123:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (/home/samir/Ahmed/Ahmed Dec 2020/Khal/vuekhal/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:121:15)
    at yargs.parse (/home/samir/Ahmed/Ahmed Dec 2020/Khal/vuekhal/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:71:45)
    at Object.parse (/home/samir/Ahmed/Ahmed Dec 2020/Khal/vuekhal/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:576:18)
    at /home/samir/Ahmed/Ahmed Dec 2020/Khal/vuekhal/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:49:8
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/samir/Ahmed/Ahmed Dec 2020/Khal/vuekhal/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:366:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:827:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685:32)
```

Comment: What's in your `package.json` file?

Comment: I have added the package.json file above

Comment: @Filburt Thanks for editing the question and making it more readable. Do you know how I can resolve this

Comment: Why do you use both webpack and grunt? Usually you would only use one of those bundlers.

Comment: The warning states, that grunt-uglify in that specified version requires your project to include grunt in version ~0.4.0. You have a newer version included, therefore the warning.

Comment: The npm audit warning states that you have vulnerable dependencies in your project. These might be dependencies of dependencies or further down the dependency tree. If npm cannot fix it automatically, it means, that your project or the dependency which is importing the vulnerable dependency requires it to be in this version. If you e.g. have in your project a `^`, minor and patch version can be updated with npm audit --fix.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 How do you suggest I fix it. I am sorry I am new at Vue. I code in Python

Comment: I would get rid of grunt and do everything with the Vue CLI and its underlying webpack build.

Comment: You mean just remove ""grunt": "^1.3.0"" from the dependencies and do "npm install"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226719/discussion-between-samir-tendulkar-and-ssc-hrep3).

Comment: I'll try remove "grunt": "^1.3.0 and see how it goes

Comment: `npm install` just downloads your dependencies. It shouldn't be a problem to have both dependencies installed. Your problem is not with installing dependencies but with running the Vue build. You are executing a prod config file for webpack. This seems to be incompatible with the newer vue-loader. Try this: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/1688

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 I added the vue version 15 it worked. If you want you can answer the question. I can mark it as the correct answer